# How to return a JSON object instead of text/html in Drupal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, drupal

I am trying to pass an id for getting the output array in Ajax but I get the type as text/html so for that I got error as *404 not found*. I need to get text/json.

PHP (Drupal):

```
function footfall_source()
{

$form['foodfall_source_submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#size' => 15,
  '#id' => 'foodfall-submit',
  '#value' => 'Fetch',
  '#name' => 'foodfall_source_submit',
  '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'foodfallList()'),
);

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $userid = $_POST['id'];
    drupal_set_message($userid);
    $output = array('success' => 'false', 'message' => 'Ajax Failed');

    drupal_json_output($output);
    drupal_exit();
}
else {
    drupal_set_message('No POST');
}  
return $form;
}
```

JavaScript with Ajax:

```
   $('#load').show();
    var foodfall_start_date = $('#foodfall-start-date').val();
    var foodfall_end_date = $('#foodfall-end-date').val();                    
                var url = '/diner/footfallsource';                   
  $.ajax({ 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'html',
  url: url,  
  data : {id : '1'},
  success: function(data){
           alert(data);
  },
  error: function(data,tt, ee){
           alert(tt+" - "+ ee); // 404 Not Found
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why your dataType is set to 'html' in your $.ajax call instead of text/json?

Comment: i tried to json also but i didnt get thats why i tried html

Comment: If you have 404 error, it's clear that the url parameter is wrong. Check the network console in your browser.

Comment: ya i checked it after than i seen in network and right click open with new tab in opening in new tab

Comment: A cool plugin you can use to test your php page (json source) is Postman (Google Chrome)

Comment: not understand please help me

Comment: i got the content type as text/html

Comment: try to set header in your php file: header('Content-Type: application/json');

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 'errors'.

- In the AJAX, you have to set the type to "json"
- In the PHP, you have to send the correct headers

Headers :

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

You can also use the [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP/) library that helps forging complex JSON if your data are multiple arrays, some objects and properties.

```
include('includes/json.php');

$json = new json();

$json->add('status', '200');
$json->add('message', 'success');
$json->add('form', $form);

$json->send();
```

Comment: Sorry for asking this question may i know class is support for drupal and i dont know how to set a header can you any samples or study document for that please help me

Comment: You set a header just like he said, by writing `header('.....');` in your function...